Does a Pandas Series Preserve the Order
let say i have this dataframe df
|  Name  |  Age | 
-----------------
|  john  |  20  |
|  gibbs |  18  |
|  jane  |  25  |

writing them in an .xlxs file using openpyxl by column
from openpyxl import Workbook

def write_by_col(ws, col, col_no):
    row = 1
    for data in col:
        ws.cell(row=row, column=col_no).value = data
        row += 1

names = df.loc[:, 'Name']
ages = df.loc[:, 'Age']

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

write_by_col(ws, names, 1)
write_by_col(ws, ages, 2)

wb.save('E:\\test.xlsx')

Can I safely always assume that what is written on the test.xlsx, is similar on the df dataframe like john has age of 20 and gibbs has 18 and lastly jane has 25?
I'm new in pandas, but it's seem to me that dataframe and series are ordered and it always preserve their ordering, unless of course there are changes, but I'm still want to confirm if my assumptions are correct, since it's not explicitly stated in their doc, though I didn't read all of it yet.
I'm aware that I can do pandas.Series.to_excel, but using openpyxl give me much more control.

In my opinion, this is the kind of question you should be asking yourself by making your own samples.

Why are you itterating through the data and not just writing the df: df.to_excel()?

@PandaKim I did make a sample and the result seem that the dataframe and series preserve the ordering of data, when I iterating and writing them in excel, but I want to confirm if my assumption are correct, that's why I'm asking this.

@gtomer This is just an example. I needed more control in my project like the placement of the columns, merging the cells of headings and more.

@Paulo - then do all the manipulation in Pandas and when you have a "ready" df - export it

It doesn't matter whether the OP is using to_excel() or some other technique to write the data to a spreadsheet. The question was whether the order in Pandas is preserved and this is IMHO not stated explicitly in the docs. So the question is legitimate. @Paulo, maybe you want to change the title of your question to something like "Does a Pandas Series Preserve the Order" to make it clearer what you actually want to know.

The ordering of rows and columns in Pandas data frames is always preserved unless you explicitly change it.  This may not be documented in a single place but it is an integral part of how Pandas works and implied in the documentation of various operations.
For example the documentation of pandas.Series.sort_values states that it returns a new pd.Series (or None).  That would not make sense if the order of values did not keep their order.
